# Not able to get .cs file in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am learning windows phone app.
[This](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/introduction-to-windows-mobile-7-development/)
is the tut used.
It asks to modify `.cs` file available in `solution explorer`. For me I can only see `.vb` file. Kindly tell me how to get `.cs` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your code in 2 different types of languages, the first one is c#, the second one is visual basic.net. You created a the Project from the type vb.net.

You can safely delete this Project and create a new one, this time with C#.
You may have to give the Project another name because the old one is still on the harddrive

Comment: Or you delete the old folder before you create the new project, normaly its under "[HD]:\Users\[urUser]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects"

Comment: Any idea how to make `visual studio` to create event handlers automatically as soon as i change xaml ?